# Exportar Tabla HTML a PDF DomPDF con MySQL y PHP

Tags: html-tabla, dompdf

El planteamiento de mi problema consiste en lo siguiente:

Estoy exportando una Tabla desde una consulta a MYSQL usando la librería DomPDF 0.6.2
pero resulta que la Cabecera y el Primer Renglón se muestran alineados a la Derecha y
el resto de Renglones, a partir del segundo aparecen bien alineados a la Izquierda.

Por lo que quisiera que por favor me ayudaran a resolver estos 4 puntos:

1. Que los renglones aparezcan alineados de forma correcta a la izquierda.
2. Que las hojas aparezcan numeradas en el PIE de la Página como 1 de 3, 2 de 3, etc.
3. Que pueda establecer el valor de los Margenes de la hoja.
4. Que pueda establecer un ENCABEZADO en cada Página.

Desde ya se los Agradezco.

Archivo index.php

```
<?php 
ob_start();
require_once('includes/conexionbd.php');  // Llama al archivo que contiene la conección a la BD.

// Abre la Conexión con la BD.
$conexion = AbreConn('dbe');

// Creo la consulta de selección SQL a la BD.
$sql = "SELECT Clientes.IdCliente, Clientes.NomRazSoc, Clientes.RFC, Clientes_Domicilios.Calle, 
Clientes_Domicilios.NumExterior, Clientes_Domicilios.NumInterior, Clientes_Domicilios.Colonia, Municipios.Municipio,
Estados.Estado, Paises.Pais, Clientes_Domicilios.CP, Clientes.Estatus 
FROM Clientes, Clientes_Domicilios, Municipios, Estados, Paises     
WHERE Clientes.IdCliente = Clientes_Domicilios.IdCliente AND Clientes_Domicilios.IdMunicipio = Municipios.IdMunicipio
AND Clientes_Domicilios.IdEstado = Estados.IdEstado AND Clientes_Domicilios.IdPais = Paises.IdPais 
AND Clientes.IdEmpresa = 1 AND Clientes_Domicilios.IdTipoDom = 1 AND RFC = 'XEXX010101000' ORDER BY Clientes.NomRazSoc ASC";
// Ejecuto la consulta de selección.
mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8"); // Función que Codifica a UTF8 para evitar errores de JSON.
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);    
?>  

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//ES" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Ejemplo de Exportación de HTML a PDF</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW,NOARCHIVE,NOODP,NOSNIPPET">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
<link href="assests/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-3.3.7.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">      
<script src="assests/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="assests/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" width="100%" height="60" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
<div class="container">
    <div class="btn btn-primary"><a href="generarpdf.php" style="color:#FFF; text-decoration:none; " target="_blank">Visualizar en PDF</a></div>  
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-14">             
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <br><p>
            <p><font face="arial" size="5" color="#000000">Ejemplo de exportación de Tabla HTML a PDF usando la librería "dompdf"</font></p> 
            <br><p>  
            <p><font face="verdana" size="3" color="#000000"><b>Clientes</b></font></p>  
            <div class="panel-body"> 
<?php               
            echo '<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive cell-border" id="TabLisClientes">';
                echo '<thead>';
                    echo '<tr style="background-color:#e6e6e6;">';
                        echo '<th>Nombre o Razón Social</th>';
                        echo '<th>R.F.C.</th>';
                        echo '<th>Calle</th>';
                        echo '<th>No.Ext.</th>';
                        echo '<th>No.Int.</th>';
                        echo '<th>Colonia</th>';
                        echo '<th>Municipio</th>';
                        echo '<th>Estado</th>';
                        echo '<th>País</th>';
                        echo '<th>C.P.</th>';
                        echo '<th>Status</th>';     
                    echo '</tr>';
                    echo '</thead>';
                    echo '<tbody>';

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $active = '';
                    if($row['Estatus'] == 'Activo') {
                        $active = '<label class="label label-success">Activo</label>';
                    } else {
                        $active = '<label class="label label-danger">Inactivo</label>'; 
                    }

                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['NomRazSoc'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['RFC'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['Calle'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['NumExterior'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['NumInterior'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['Colonia'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['Municipio'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['Estado'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['Pais'].'</td>';               
                        echo '<td>'.$row['CP'].'</td>';             
                        echo '<td>'.$active.'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';                       
                    } // Fin while 

                    // Cierra la Conexión con la BD.
                    mysqli_close($conexion);

                    echo '</tbody>';
                echo '</table>';
            ?>  
            </div> <!-- / panel-body -->
        </div> <!-- / panel panel-default -->               
    </div> <!-- / col-md-14 -->
</div> <!-- / row -->
</div> <!-- / container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Archivo generarpdf.php

```
<?php 
ob_start();
require_once('includes/conexionbd.php');  // Llama al archivo que contiene la conección a la BD.

// Abre la Conexión con la BD.
$conexion = AbreConn('dbe');

// Creo la consulta de selección SQL a la BD.
$sql = "SELECT Clientes.IdCliente, Clientes.NomRazSoc, Clientes.RFC, Clientes_Domicilios.Calle, 
Clientes_Domicilios.NumExterior, Clientes_Domicilios.NumInterior, Clientes_Domicilios.Colonia, Municipios.Municipio,
Estados.Estado, Paises.Pais, Clientes_Domicilios.CP, Clientes.Estatus 
FROM Clientes, Clientes_Domicilios, Municipios, Estados, Paises     
WHERE Clientes.IdCliente = Clientes_Domicilios.IdCliente AND Clientes_Domicilios.IdMunicipio = Municipios.IdMunicipio
AND Clientes_Domicilios.IdEstado = Estados.IdEstado AND Clientes_Domicilios.IdPais = Paises.IdPais 
AND Clientes.IdEmpresa = 1 AND Clientes_Domicilios.IdTipoDom = 1 AND RFC = 'XEXX010101000' ORDER BY Clientes.NomRazSoc ASC";
// Ejecuto la consulta de selección.
mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8"); // Función que Codifica a UTF8 para evitar errores de JSON.
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);    
?>  

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//ES" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Ejemplo de Exportación de HTML a PDF</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW,NOARCHIVE,NOODP,NOSNIPPET">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
<link href="assests/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-3.3.7.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">      
<script src="assests/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="assests/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" width="100%" height="60" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
<div class="container">
    <div class="btn btn-primary"><a href="generarpdf.php" style="color:#FFF; text-decoration:none; " target="_blank">Visualizar en PDF</a></div>  
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-14">             
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <br><p>
            <p><font face="arial" size="5" color="#000000">Ejemplo de exportación de Tabla HTML a PDF usando la librería "dompdf"</font></p> 
            <br><p>  
            <p><font face="verdana" size="3" color="#000000"><b>Clientes</b></font></p>  
            <div class="panel-body"> 
<?php               
            echo '<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive cell-border" id="TabLisClientes">';
                echo '<thead>';
                    echo '<tr style="background-color:#e6e6e6;">';
                        echo '<th>Nombre o Razón Social</th>';
                        echo '<th>R.F.C.</th>';
                        echo '<th>Calle</th>';
                        echo '<th>No.Ext.</th>';
                        echo '<th>No.Int.</th>';
                        echo '<th>Colonia</th>';
                        echo '<th>Municipio</th>';
                        echo '<th>Estado</th>';
                        echo '<th>País</th>';
                        echo '<th>C.P.</th>';
                        echo '<th>Status</th>';     
                    echo '</tr>';
                    echo '</thead>';
                    echo '<tbody>';

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $active = '';
                    if($row['Estatus'] == 'Activo') {
                        $active = '<label class="label label-success">Activo</label>';
                    } else {
                        $active = '<label class="label label-danger">Inactivo</label>'; 
                    }

                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['NomRazSoc'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['RFC'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['Calle'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['NumExterior'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['NumInterior'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['Colonia'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['Municipio'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['Estado'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['Pais'].'</td>';               
                        echo '<td>'.$row['CP'].'</td>';             
                        echo '<td>'.$active.'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';                       
                    } // Fin while 

                    // Cierra la Conexión con la BD.
                    mysqli_close($conexion);

                    echo '</tbody>';
                echo '</table>';
            ?>  
            </div> <!-- / panel-body -->
        </div> <!-- / panel panel-default -->               
    </div> <!-- / col-md-14 -->
</div> <!-- / row -->
</div> <!-- / container -->
</body>
</html>
<?php
# Cargamos la librería dompdf.
require_once 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

# Instanciamos un objeto de la clase DOMPDF.
$mipdf = new DOMPDF();

# Definimos el tamaño y orientación del papel que queremos.
# O por defecto cogerá el que está en el fichero de configuración.
$mipdf ->set_paper("Legal", "landscape");

# Cargamos el contenido HTML.
$mipdf ->load_html(ob_get_clean());

# Renderizamos el documento PDF.
$mipdf ->render();

# Enviamos el fichero PDF al navegador.
$mipdf->stream("Clientes.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

exit(0);
?>
```

Esta es la imagen de la Tabla de la Consulta a MYSQL (Archivo index.php):

[image: Esta es la imagen de la Tabla de la Consulta a MYSQL]

Esta es la imagen del PDF de la tabla Exportada (Archivo generar.php):

[image: Esta es la imagen del PDF de la tabla Exportada]

Answer (score 0):

La solución al problema de alineación la encontre aquí mismo en stack overflow, en esta url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596910/dompdf-does-not-render-table-nicely

La puse entre las etiquetas de la página o Archivo generarpdf.php que muestro a continuación (es la última línea relacionada con los estilos):

```
<head>
<title>Ejemplo de Exportación de HTML a PDF</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW,NOARCHIVE,NOODP,NOSNIPPET">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
<link href="assests/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-3.3.7.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">      
<script src="assests/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="assests/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
<style type="text/css"> thead:before, thead:after { display: none; } tbody:before, tbody:after { display: none; } </style>
</head>
```

Este es el Resultado después de agregar la línea de estilos antes mencionada:

[image: Este es el Resultado después de agregar la línea de estilos antes mencionada]

Gracias a Pathros https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883256/pathros

Ahora solo necesito resolver los 3 puntos restantes, a saber:

2. Que las hojas aparezcan numeradas en el PIE de la Página como 1 de 3, 2 de 3, etc.
3. Que pueda establecer el valor de los Margenes de la hoja.
4. Que pueda establecer un ENCABEZADO en cada Página.

¿Podrían ayudarme con dichos puntos por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Ya están resueltos los 3 puntos restantes de mi problema, que eran los siguientes:

1. Que las hojas aparezcan numeradas en el PIE de la Página como 1 de 3, 2 de 3, etc.
2. Que pueda establecer el valor de los Margenes de la hoja.
3. Que pueda establecer un ENCABEZADO en cada Página.

La solución consistió en modificar código en el Archivo generarpdf.php de la manera que describo a continuación:

Desmarqué la línea "define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP", true);" en el archivo "dompdf_config.custom.inc.php" de la librería "dompdf".

Agregué la línea "require_once 'dompdf/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php';" inmediatamente después de la línea "require_once 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';".

Eliminé las etiquetas "", "", y "", junto con los textos

```
<br><p>
<p><font face="arial" size="5" color="#000000">Ejemplo de exportación de Tabla HTML a PDF usando la librería "dompdf"</font></p> 
<br><p>  
<p><font face="verdana" size="3" color="#000000"><b>Clientes</b></font></p>  
<div class="panel-body">
```

Agregue las siguientes líneas antes de la etiqueta "" y después de la etiqueta "":

```
<script type="text/php">
if ( isset($pdf) ) {
    // OLD 
    $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("Arial", "normal");
    $pdf->page_text(960, 590, "{PAGE_NUM} de {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
    // v.0.7.0 and greater
    /*$x = 72;
    $y = 18;
    $text = "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}";
    $font = $fontMetrics->get_font("helvetica", "bold");
    $size = 6;
    $color = array(255,0,0);
    $word_space = 0.0;  //  default
    $char_space = 0.0;  //  default
    $angle = 0.0;   //  default
    $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color, $word_space, $char_space, $angle);*/
}
</script>   
<div id="header">Cabecera de Página</div>
<div id="footer">Pie de Página</div>
```

Finalmente agregué las últimas 3 líneas de estilo en la etiqueta siguiente:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
thead:before, thead:after { display: none; } tbody:before, tbody:after { display: none; }
@page { margin: 40px 10px; }
#header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: -32px; right: 0px; height: 40px; background-color: orange; text-align: center; }
#footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: -32px; right: 0px; height: 30px; background-color: lightblue; text-align: center; }       
</style>
```

Y el Resultado Final fue el Siguiente:

[image: Y el Resultado Final fue el Siguiente]

GRACIAS!